# SearchView as part of the AlertDialog

Tags: android

[This is posted on Android Developer's forum as well]

I am trying to place the search widget [`SearchView` basically] in the
title part of an `AlertDialog`. Is that allowed, i.e. will it work? The
idea is to have the user enter a search word and when he/she presses
the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the keyboard, to use the search word entered to
search through an array of strings and display the result as a
`listView` in the same `AlertDialog`'s body portion. The following is the
piece of relevant code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new
AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

RelativeLayout titleLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
SearchView sv = new SearchView(this);
titleLayout.addView(sv);

dialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(titleLayout);
```

When I run this code, I see the search widget in the title alright.
The Virtual/Soft keyboard pops up when I click inside the search box -
but I am unable to type in it because the `AlertDialog` disappears as
soon as I click anywhere outside of it (as it should). I am wondering
if the keyboard is associated with the activity that is launching the
`AlertDialog` instead of being in the context of the `AlertDialog` itself.

Any ideas?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, but `android.app.Dialog` implements `android.view.KeyEvent.Callback`, so you should be able to override

`public abstract boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

and

`public abstract boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

to just `return true` and thus capturing the `KeyEvent` without any further action.

Comment: did not help, unfortunately. Maybe, i am not doing it the way are thinking. Posted below is the code....    

dialogBuilder.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
@Override
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
  KeyEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Log.v(TAG, "onKey.............");
 return true;
}});

I don't even see the OnKeyListener getting fired...